# Ubuntu 22.04 Audacity does not show up in PulseAudio Recording tab

Tags: pulseaudio, 22.04, audacity

Fresh install Ubuntu 22.04. Installed `pavucontrol` via apt.

I can record from microphone. But I want to record from system mix output.

Tried following Audacity tutorial: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_linux.html
But got stuck at Step 5

> In the "Capture from" dropdown, select the "Monitor" option

-- This tab is empty.
[image: empty pavucontrol]

More problems:

If I open Audacity first, start Monitoring microphone, I can see the levels, and I can start recording.

If I open Audacity, then open `pavucontrol`, then go back to Audacity, when I start monitoring or start recording, it will complain "error -9985 cannot open device".

---

Note: A separate issue with "not seeing Audacity in Pulse Audio Volume Control" --

You will need to either use "Start Monitoring" over the microphone level meter, or start recording (you may pause, but cannot stop)

Answer (score 2):

My solution to problems with recording in Audacity was to uninstall the Snap version:

```
sudo snap remove audacity
```

and then install from the repository:

```
sudo apt install audacity -y
```

The older version in the repo isn't a big deal for me, since my needs are pretty basic. I'm also on 22.04, and it worked immediately with no tweaking at all.

Comment: This is a very good workaround, but I'm hesitant to accept it as answer -- Will the APT version be dropped in the future? I don't want it to be a "this worked for me back then" kind of thing

Comment: Strangely I got audacity edge snap working with pulse by disallowing ALSA with `sudo snap disconnect audacity:alsa`.. even recording works while `audacity:audio-record` is still disconnected. `snap connections audacity` just shows pulseaudio and audio-playback as connected audio slots.

Comment: `~/snap/audacity/common` should have a file `Always use PulseAudio` with `ALWAYS_USE_PULSEAUDIO=1` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, PulseAudio and ALSA are mutually exclusive.
As user2859 suggested in the comment, not connecting to (or disconnecting from) ALSA helped, which is, to run `sudo snap disconnect audacity:alsa`.

Comment: woked for me with the snap, but in pavucontrol set the intput device to monitor to create the right default as well.

Answer (score 0):

This one works decent for ubuntu 22.04 [gnome sound recorder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SoundRecorder)

sudo apt-get install gnome-sound-recorder -y

make sure the input microphone is on as well, in ubuntu 22.04 sometimes it was turned off for some reason.